# Could I get ENOENT error if file is busy in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, readfile, node-modules

io/fs and, have the tool written in node which reading the file and convert data from file. And it was working fine, that I converted that tool to use some other tool for banching and now I saw in log some ENOENT errors and it happens in some random way. So I doubt that this issue could be generated because this file left opened and when another banch process start file is opened and tool can't open that same file. Am I wrong, and what else could be problem?

Comment: `ENOENT` means the file doesn't exist.

Comment: yeah, i know that, but still wondering can anything else cause that error. I found one more think that machine where the tool is deployed has .29 version of node, and also checked change log of node for latest version and there is a lot of changes on fs module, so I made request for updating node, so I'll check tomorrow, that could be problem, because on my machine I have .32 and simply can't reproduce the issue.